# Prove that $f(v,w):=L_1(v)L_2(w)$ is a bilinear form on V

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be a vector space over the field F and let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be linear functions on V. Prove that
>
> $$f(v,w):=L_1(v)L_2(w)$$
>
> is a bilinear form on V

I kinda think that fixing v could help, but I am having trouble with notation, can I get some help?

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of verifying the definition of *bilinear*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fixing $v$, we get $w\mapsto f(v,w) =L_1(v)L_2(w)$ is a linear functional, namely it is $\lambda\cdot L_2$ where $\lambda=L_1(v)$ is a fixed scalar.
Similarly, fixing $w$, we get $v\mapsto L_1(v)L_2(w)$ is linear.